# How can I set a working breakpoint to a constant expression?

Tags: perl, debugging, breakpoints, constant-expression

I have Perl code that uses a constant with an initializing block like this:

```
use constant C => map {
    ...;
} (0..255);
```

When I try to *set a breakpoint* at the `...;` line, it does not work, meaning: I *can set* the breakpoint, but the debugger *does not stop* there.

I tried:

1. Start the program with the debugger (`perl -d program.pl`)
2. Set the breakpoint in the debugger (`b 2`)
3. Reload using `R`, then run (`r`) the program

But still the debugger did not stop at the line, just as if I had no breakpoint set.

My Perl is not the latest; it's 5.18.2, just in case it matters...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to put a break point in a `use` block.
A use block is in effect a `BEGIN` block with a `require` in it.
The Perl debugger by default does not stop in compile phase.
However you can force the Perl debugger into single step mode inside a `BEGIN` block by setting the variable `$DB::single` to `1`

See `Debugging Compile-Time Statements` in `perldoc perldebug`

If you change your code to

```
use constant C => map {
    $DB::single = 1;
    ...;
} (0..255);
```

The Perl debugger will stop in the use statement.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid modifying the source (like some command line switch)?

Comment: @U.Windl not that I know of

Comment: I've illustrated a means of avoiding code modification in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid altering your code if you create a simple module like this ([concept originated here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Debug::Phases)):

```
package StopBegin;

BEGIN {
    $DB::single=1;
}
1;
```

Then, run your code as

```
perl -I./  -MStopBegin -d test.pl
```

**Pertinent Answer (previous, not-so-pertinent answer is below this one)**

If test.pl looks like this:

```
use constant C => {
    map {;
        "C$_" => $_;
    } 0 .. 255
};
```

here's what the debug interaction looks like:

```
% perl -I./  -MStopBegin -d test.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.53
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

StopBegin::CODE(0x55db6287dac0)(StopBegin.pm:8):
8:  1;
  DB<1> s
main::CODE(0x55db6287db38)(test.pl:5):
5:  };
  DB<1> -
1   use constant C => {
2:      map {;
3:          "C$_" => $_;
4       } 0 .. 255
5==>    };
  DB<2> b 3
  DB<3> c
main::CODE(0x55db6287db38)(test.pl:3):
3:          "C$_" => $_;
  DB<3>
```

Note the use of the breakpoint to stop inside the `map`.

**Previous, Not-So-Pertinent Answer**

If `test.pl` looks like this:

```
my $foo;

BEGIN {
    $foo = 1;
};
```

here's what the debug interaction looks like:

```
% perl -I./  -MStopBegin -d test.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.53
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

StopBegin::CODE(0x5567e3d79a80)(StopBegin.pm:8):
8:  1;
  DB<1> s
main::CODE(0x5567e40f0db0)(test.pl:4):
4:      $foo = 1;
  DB<1> s
main::(test.pl:1):  my $foo;
  DB<1> s
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1>
```

Note the use of the `s` command to advance, otherwise it'll skip over the `BEGIN` block in `test.pl`

Comment: I had a similar idea using an environment variable to enable `$DB::single = 1` conditionally.